# What's the difference between this function and the lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int* New()
{
    return new int(666);
}
int Foo()
{
    //method1:
    int* it = New();
    return *it;
    //method2:
    return []() { return *(new int(666)); };//Complier has a complain here
    /*Both New() and Lambda are callable object, are there any differences between method1 and method2?*/ 
}
int main()
{
    cout << Foo() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm fresh in C++, I encounter a situation above, I had review the chapter 10.3.2 to 10.3.3 of C++ Primer, where introduces the lambda expression.But it doesn't work for me, I'm also confused about the last annotation I list.

Comment: You called `New`. You didn't call the lambda. Also, C is not C++.

Comment: Also, you're leaking everything you allocate.

Comment: Here what I mean is I will wipe off the method1 if I select method. Could you give me more some details?

Comment: @Ryan, compiler give me a error is : there no such convertable funtion from "lambda []int ()->int" to "int"

Comment: You didn't *call* the lambda.

Comment: Oh! I got it. I review the words from C++ Primer "We call a lambda the same way we call funtion by using the call operator"

Answer (score 2):

```
return []() { return *(new int(666)); };
```

This line is trying to return the lambda itself.  You want to *call* the lambda and return the integer that it produces:

```
return []() { return *(new int(666)); }();  // Note the () at the end
```

There's generally not much point in defining a lambda function only to immediately call it, though.  They're more commonly used when you need to actually return a function, or take one as an argument.  (This is a more advanced thing to do, though, so you probably shouldn't worry about it for now.)

---

On a separate note: your program allocates integers with `new`, but it never releases them with `delete`.  This is a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), which is something you should avoid.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just write this small instance in haste， and will care more by ur note.

Answer (score 0):

Actuall, I didn't call my lambda because it lacks the call operator.
So, I fix it as:

```
return []() { return *(new int(666)); }();
```

It works now.

I review the words from Chapter of 10.3.2 of C++ Primer "We call a lambda the same way we call funtion by using the call operator".